# FaultException during sending messages to ServiceBus queue in a batch

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to send a couple of messages to a service bus queue in a batch. I am doing it by using [`SendBatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.sendbatch?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_SendBatch_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage__) method of [`QueueClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet).

I am getting a `FaultException` during this operation:

> Batching brokered messages with distinct SessionId, PartitionKey, or
>   MessageId is not supported for an entity with partitioning and
>   duplicate detection enabled.

The exception's message is quite self-explanatory, and I would try to fix it, but sometimes it works, no exceptions are thrown.

So sometimes it throws an exception, sometimes it works. I do not change any settings of queues and I do not change the code.

Any ideas why it can happen?

Comment: Can it be that when it succeeds, then actually the whole batch belongs to the same single session?

Comment: And you can confirm that when it works, it's the same state of entities/messages? Are you sending in the context of an incoming message ("send-via")?

Comment: @Mikhail we do not use session explicitly, can it be used implicitly because we cache and reuse QueueClient?

Comment: @SeanFeldman not sure what you mean by the same state, but the messages we send differ only in domain-specific values, we do not assign any value to `messageid` or `partitionkey` or `sessionid`. And, no, we are not sending in the context of an incoming message.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda Ok... but is your queue partitioned and is duplicate detection enabled?

Comment: @Mikhail it is, and I would be okay if it didn't work, but it works sometimes with the same exact queue.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda It doesn't make sense to enable duplicate detection and not to assign message ID, since IDs are used for duplicate detection...

Comment: @Mikhail makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and was helped by this post:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/103

what I realize is that the exception message is actually incorrect. It gives the impression that “distinct … MessageId  is not supported with … duplicate detection enabled” when in fact it  is required!

so after I create a message:
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<..JsonString...>));

I added this line of code and it worked:

message.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

Answer (score 1):

This was likely because your batch contained messages that would go into different partitions. A batch must contain messages for only one partition. In my case, my partition was the SessionId, so I first grouped my messages by SessionId, then batched by those groups and it worked great.

```
var bySessionId = messages.GroupBy(s => s.SessionId);
foreach (var sessionSet in bySessionId)
{
    var msgBatch = sessionSet.Batch(20); //Using .Batch from MoreLinq
    foreach (var b in msgBatch)
    {
        var sbb = await sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
        b.ForEach(m => sbb.TryAddMessage(m));

        await sender.SendMessagesAsync(sbb);
    }
}
```