# Batching brokered messages with distinct SessionId or PartitionKey is not supported for an entity with partitioning enabled

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to `Peek` a message from Queue1 and send that message to Queue2. Both the queues are **Partition-enabled**.

I am able to peek a message successfully, but when I try to send it, I get the below exception:

> Batching brokered messages with distinct SessionId or PartitionKey is not supported for an entity with partitioning enabled.LogicalPartitionId:45::PartitionKey:5::SessionId:5::MessageId:c2d57b0a-fff8-40bc-a835-d335eec0eade::ViaPartitionKey:::

The `PartitionKey` and `SessionId` are same, which is `5` in my case. So there's no difference. The queues *do not* have `DuplicateDetectionEnabled`. They are just simple partitioned queues.
Also, I am just sending a single message, hence no batching is involved (The exception however talks about batching). Where am I going wrong?

Note: I am using Service Bus SDK 7.4.0.

```cs
var receiverClient = serviceBusSourceClient.CreateReceiver("queue1");
var message = await receiverClient.PeekMessageAsync();
var senderClient = serviceBusDestinationClient.CreateSender("queue2");
await senderClient.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(message));
```

Comment: Seems like related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638857/faultexception-during-sending-messages-to-servicebus-queue-in-a-batch take a look

Comment: Thanks @jdresc, the question you are referring to is a batch operation, so the error is straight forward in that case. In my case, there is just a single message and no batching involved.

Comment: Does the issue reproduce every time?

Comment: Yes, @joshlove. It's been a week since I tried this, and it's still reproduceable.

Comment: Can you try enabling logging? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md#logging

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Josh Love](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16249465/josh-love), you can try enabling logging to find the cause of this error `Batching brokered messages with distinct SessionId or PartitionKey is not supported for an entity with partitioning`

```
// Setup a listener to monitor logged events.

using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();
```